# Moment.js and Chart.js not working in Firefox Addon when Type time is specified

Tags: javascript, chart.js, momentjs

I've created a firefox addon with:

My manifest includes:

```
"content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": [
        "..."          ],
      "js": [
        "moment.js",
        "jquery.js",
        "chartjs.js",
        "main.js"
      ],
      "run_at": "document_end"
    }
  ]
```

main.js includes:

```
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
      type: 'line',
      data: {
        datasets: [{
          label: label,
          lineTension: 0,
          backgroundColor: color,
          data: data
        }]
      },
      options: {
        scales: {
          xAxes: [{
            type: "time",
            distribution: 'linear',
            time: {
              unit: "day"
            }
          }]
        }
      }
    });
```

This works in my Chrome extension, but when I port it to Firefox addon, it shows a blank chart. Even the jsfiddle works in both: https://jsfiddle.net/a9yzuxjf/1/

I've removed the 'type: "time"' and it renders, but the chart isn't a time series like I want. Could this be something to do with moment.js not loading properly?

Comment: Thank you for posting this question, my extension also starts "working" if I remove the `type: "time"`, so I likely have the same issue. Shame there's no solutions or workarounds posted on SO yet (neither here, nor on [your other, related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51948350/419956)...

Comment: I think it might be a bug with chart.js, and [I've logged it as an issue in their repository](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/issues/5901).