# moment.js is not loading before chart.js in Firefox extension

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, chart.js, momentjs

I am porting a Chrome extension to Firefox and it adds Chartjs charts to a page. It requires moment.js and works great on Chrome. However, when I port it to Firefox, the charts don't load and I get an error:

**Error: Chart.js - Moment.js could not be found! You must include it before Chart.js to use the time scale. Download at https://momentjs.com**

My manifest.json has the content scripts in the order they need to load, but Chartjs can't seem to 'find' moment js when the charts are populated.

```
"content_scripts": [
    {
        "matches": [
            "<site this should be active on>"
        ],
        "css": [
            "main.css"
        ],
        "js": [
            "jquery.js",
            "moment.js",
            "chartjs.js",
            "main.js"
        ]
    }
]
```

I've hunted and hunted on Google to no luck. Please help!

Comment: it could be a bug in firefox; known to have happened before https://discourse.mozilla.org/t/order-of-execution-of-content-scripts-in-mozilla-web-extension/14365
and 
https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1347700

Comment: I landed here after looking at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51011867/419956) by OP. I _don't think it's a Firefox bug_ because then you get a console error *"Chart.js - Moment.js could not be found! You must include it before..."* - and I'm not getting that error (unless I explicitly break the manifest content scripts order).

Answer (score 1):

**Update**: with help of a Chart.js contributor we've confirmed that it's a bug with Chart.js' way of loading things, see [this comment and above](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/issues/5901#issuecomment-445534641) for details. So below workaround is probably as good as it gets for now.

---

I ran into the same issue, and I made a [bug report for it on the Chart.js repository](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/issues/5901). I also found a workaround, which is to add this to `moment.min.js` when building/packing your extension:

```
// Minified momentjs code on this line;
window.moment = moment;
```

In my case I use Powershell to dump files into a `build` folder:

```bsh
Remove-Item build -Recurse -Force -Confirm:$false
mkdir build

Copy-Item node_modules/moment/min/moment.min.js build/
Copy-Item node_modules/chart.js/dist/Chart.js build/
Copy-Item src/js/app.js build/app.js
Copy-Item manifest.json build/manifest.json

# Workaround for: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51948350/
# See also: https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/issues/5901
Add-Content -Path build/moment.min.js -Value "`n`nwindow.moment = moment;"
```

Not really a solution or answer, but useful enough to post I suppose...